# Switching tabs in search results breaks case sensitive code searches

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

When you switch tabs in the search results the search string gets lower cased. This normally doesn't have an impact on the search results unless you do a  `code:` search.

This can be worked around if you modify the url e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=code%3a%22fooBar%22

Can you not change the case of the query string when switching tabs and when doing code searches?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code searches are now case-insensitive in [the new search engine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange) (soon the default), so this won't be an issue anymore...marking this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).