# Add code search syntax to search tips

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, help

After [Search just code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55473/search-just-code) we now have a way to search code, so something like `code:"-->"` searches for the infamous `-->` "operator". [(Protip: it's not an operator, it's two)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1642035/869458)

Could this be added to the [Search Tips](https://stackoverflow.com/search) page so it's discoverable? On Stack Overflow it's extremely helpful, and I only just heard about it a year after joining SO and being very active on the network.

Comment: Yeah. I didn't know you could search code like that, either.

Comment: I hope they do this and that they note that the searches [are case sensitive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134835/148672)

Comment: how does this even get done? i have the [privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) but not the [opportunity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching)!

Comment: That's **not** a great UI for performing such a search. It *works* to use `code::set` on emacs.SE, but it's not very clear that you're really looking for the exact string **`:set`**. Maybe more importantly, it's not clear that people will think to do (or find out how to do) `code:` to search for a literal sequence of chars.

Comment: Eh, @adam - if you're planning to fix symbol indexing as part of this, might wanna roll back the change here too: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368516/search-for-special-characters-isnt-working-as-advertised

Comment: @Shog9 Well, that sounds like... not much fun at all, but into the backlog it goes.

Answer (score 19):

We've finally added the `code:"x"` syntax into the search tips on [/search](https://stackoverflow.com/search)! It only took us... *checking my notes here* ...8 years. Oof. Sorry about that. Thanks for the request, we really appreciate it.

Comment: No one is complaining. Between [6 to 8](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/158100) is what we expect  ... :D

Comment: This deserves 600-800 rep.