# Add ability to craft regex expressions for the Search Bar

Tags: feature-request, search-engine

Another question "[Add code search syntax to search tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146546/add-code-search-syntax-to-search-tips#313308)" gave me this idea for a feature request:

> Something like `code:"-->"` searches for the infamous `--` `>` "operators". (Protip: it's not an operator, it's two). Could this be added to the Search Tips page so it's discoverable?

My feature request is for something more powerful (running at a lower priority, so as not to hog the cycles); that avoids further exception requests and maintaining the documentation for each.

Could we **implement [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)** on the search engine, (and document such 'specialty searches', after their implementation, in the 'search help').

This would allow programmers whom are looking for one or more specific occurences of character strings, interspersed with other unknown characters, to find their desired results.